# Date picker javascript and email check ajax java script error

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a form html which has date of birth field and email field. I am using date picker for bate of birth field which is working fine .For email field.I am using ajax to validate email.email validation is not working.
i am using the below code,

**HTML**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>TIME MANAGEMENT</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family:Verdana; font-size:20px }
        td   { padding: 2px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px }
        .input_s1_normal   { width: 150; height: 15; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; border: 1px solid black; }
        .input_s1_focus    { background: #efefef; }
        .button_s1   { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registration.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
        <script>
        $(function()  {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
        });
        </script>
        <script src="js/check.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="chkForm" id="chkForm" method="POST" action="condition.php">
        Name<input type="text" name="empname" value=""/><br/>
        <p>
            DOB <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="empdob" value="" /><br/><!--d-m-y-->
        </p>
        <?php
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("harisan", $link);

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM designation", $link);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($num_rows>0)
            {
                echo "Designation <select name='position'><br/>";
                while($result1= mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo    "<option value='".$result1['design_name']."'>".$result1['design_name']."
                    </option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";   
            }
        ?>  
        <br/>
        Email<input id="email"  type="text"  name="email" /><br/>
        <div id="emailInfo" align="left"></div>
        <input type="submit"   name="signup" value="submit"></input>
        <a href="view_list.php" value="">view</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#B1').attr('disabled','');
    var emailok = false;
    var boxes = $(".input_s1_normal");
    var myForm = $("#chkForm"), email = $("#email"), emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");

    //give some effect on focus
    boxes.focus(function(){
        $(this).addClass("input_s1_focus");
    });
    //reset on blur
    boxes.blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("input_s1_focus");
    });

    //Form Validation
    myForm.submit(function(){

        if(email.attr("value") == "")
        {
            alert("Enter Email");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(!emailok)
        {
            alert("Check Email");
            email.attr("value","");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    //send ajax request to check email
    email.blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "email="+$(this).attr("value"),
            url: "check.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                emailInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Checking Email...</font>");
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "invalid")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Invalid Email</font>");
                }
                else if(data != "0")
                {
                    emailok = false;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Email Already Exist</font>");
                }
                else 
                {
                    emailok = true;
                    emailInfo.html("<font color='green'>Email OK</font>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know what is the problem.Please help
I am new to javascript. email validation not working.it is always reviwing showing *invalid email* .
  I used this URL: https://beski.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/check-email-already-exist-ajax-jquery/

Comment: provide more information, about how this is not working. What are you  expecting for and what are you receiving from script?

Comment: And probably you have a logical error : clicking on button submit using your mouse after typing your email - will submit your form with out verification process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is inside your check.php (wich you didnt include). If you use a regular expression in your check.php to validate your email I woud try replacing it with this code and see if it works:

```
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //Valid email!
   }
```